# error: Error parsing XML: not well-formed (invalid token)

Tags: xml, parsing, resources

drawable/icondrawable/icon

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources
    <string name="app_name">MerjProject</string>
    <string name="hello">Hello World!</string>
    <string name="menu_settings">Settings</string>
    <string name="ref">this is a reference</string>
</resources>
```

Where have i gone wrong??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your XML file is missing a `>` in the second line:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string name="app_name">MerjProject</string>
    <string name="hello">Hello World!</string>
    <string name="menu_settings">Settings</string>
    <string name="ref">this is a reference</string>
</resources>
```